# Use Countif in ssrs expression

Tags: reporting-services

I want the below result in ssrs expression. In excel I have used countif function to resolved this but i didn't get similar function in ssrs.

Excel formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(H1:K1,"C")>0,"C",IF(COUNTIF(H1:K1,"B")>0,"B","A"))
```

Result:

```
H   I   J   K   Final
A   B   A   A   B
A   A   A   A   A
A   B   A   A   B
A   C   A   A   C
```

I have used above formula in Final column. I want same output in ssrs expression.

Comment: you need to show more info, in particular, what does your raw data look like? I assume it's not stored in the structure shown in your example.

Comment: SSRS doesn't use Excel formulas and it can't refer to Cells. In SSRS you would write something like this to get the lowest grade in a table grouped by student: `=Min(Fields!Grade.Value, "StudentGroup")`

Answer (score 1):

**Ass**u**me**ing that your field names are H, I, J, K, your expression would look like this:

```
=IIF(Fields.H.Value = "C" OR Fields.I.Value = "C" OR Fields.J.Value = "C" OR Fields.K.Value = "C", "C",
 IIF(Fields.H.Value = "B" OR Fields.I.Value = "B" OR Fields.J.Value = "B" OR Fields.K.Value = "B", "B", "A"))
```

This read as IF H, I, J, or K are C then C else if H, I, J, or K are B then B else A.

If you were summing rows instead of columns, you would make something a little closer to the CountIF function:

```
=IIF(SUM(IIF(Fields!H.Value = "C", 1, 0)) > 0, "C", ...
```